# Loop within .map jQuery

Tags: jquery, function

I need to get the ID of all span elements, but when I get one I need to get the ID of the images as well.

```
$('#showChild').append('Found <b>' + $('#Container > span').length + '</b> child SPAN elements <br />');

// SHOW THE CHILD DIV'S.
$('#Container > span').map(function() {
    $('#showChild').append(this.id + '<br />');
    alert(this.id);
    var id=this.id;
    alert(id);
    //CODE BELOW DOES NOT WORK
    $('#' + id + '> img').map(function() {
        $('#showChild').append(this.id + '<br />');
    });   
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="Container">
    <span id="Span1"></span>
    <img id="img1" />
    <img id="img2" />
    <span id="Span2"></span>
    <img id="img3" />
    <img id="img4" />
</div>

<!--DISPLAY THE CHILD DIV's-->
<div id="showChild"></div>
```

Comment: You need `$('#' + id + ' + img')` instead of `$('#' + id + '> img')`. The `img` is adjacent to the `span`, not a descendant of it

Answer (score 0):

You need to use siblings() function

```
  $(window).load(function () {
        $('#showChild').append('Found <b>' + $('#Container > span').length + '</b> child SPAN elements <br />');

// SHOW THE CHILD DIV'S.
        $('#Container > span').map(function() {
            $('#showChild').append(this.id + '<br />');
            alert(this.id);
            var id=this.id;
            alert(id);
            //CODE BELOW DOES NOT WORK
            $(this).siblings('img').map(function() {
                $('#showChild').append(this.id + '<br />');
            });
        });
    });
```

or you might need to put the images inside the spans
not sure if that was the intention.

another method

```
    $(window).load(function () {
        $('#showChild').append('Found <b>' + $('#Container > span').length + '</b> child SPAN elements <br />');

// SHOW THE CHILD DIV'S.
        $('#Container > span, #Container > img').map(function() {
            $('#showChild').append(this.id + '<br />');
            alert(this.id);
            var id=this.id;
            alert(id);

        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks AceWeb; $('#Container > span, #Container > img') produced the correct result:

the output is:

Found 2 child SPAN elements 
Span1
img1
img2
Span2
img3
img4

The HTML is the same as originally above.

Comment: I plan to produce this string: Span1||img1|img2|Span2||img3|img4| and pass to an Ajax function. This will allow users to drag and drop images between spans which are really categories.

Comment: Actually the string is: 
||Span1|img1|img2||Span2|img3|img4| -- which will work with a .net split.

Answer (score 0):

The img tags are not inside the span element. You should add the img element inside the span to get it worked.

```
 <div id="Container">
 <span id="Span1">
   <img id="img1" /><img id="img2" /></span>
 <span id="Span2"><img id="img3" /><img id="img4" /></span>
 </div>
 <!--DISPLAY THE CHILD DIV's-->
 <div id="showChild"></div>
```